# HDP 2.0 Oozie Error: E0803 : E0803: IO error, E0603

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

I am new to Apache Oozie and I am trying to run map-reduce example from Oozie examples using Hortonwors HDP 2.0 platform. I am getting:

```
[jakub@puppetmaster main]$ oozie job -oozie http://puppetmaster:11000/oozie -config apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
Error: E0803 : E0803: IO error, E0603: SQL error in operation, <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred. FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@2e4263ee
```

I suspect that I didn't performed some of the installations instruction correctly. I purely followed HDP 2.0 installation manual but I wasn't sure under which user to run commands. So I did following set of steps:

```
su -
cd /usr/lib/oozie/
bin/oozie-setup.sh prepare-war
cd /usr/lib/oozie/
bin/ooziedb.sh create -sqlfile oozie.sql -run Validate DB Connection
su oozie
cd /usr/lib/oozie/
/usr/lib/oozie/bin/oozie-start.sh
```

Smoke test

```
oozie admin -oozie http://$oozie.full.hostname:11000/oozie -status
```

were ok.

I am using build in debry databese shipped with distribution rpm package.
Property file for the job:

```
nameNode=hdfs://puppetmaster:8020
jobTracker=puppetmaster:8050
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples

oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/map-reduce
outputDir=map-reduce
```

I am not sure 100% sure if address of job tracker is correct pointing to yarn resource manager.

Workflow file for the example.

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="map-reduce-wf">
    <start to="mr-node"/>
    <action name="mr-node">
        <map-reduce>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data/${outputDir}"/>
            </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.oozie.example.SampleMapper</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.oozie.example.SampleReducer</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
                    <value>1</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                    <value>/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/input-data/text</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                    <value>/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data/${outputDir}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Map/Reduce failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Logs

```
2014-06-11 11:01:45,705 ERROR SubmitXCommand:536 - USER[jakub] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000000-140611110030961-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[-] XException, 
org.apache.oozie.command.CommandException: E0803: IO error, E0603: SQL error in operation, <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@355319a8
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.SubmitXCommand.execute(SubmitXCommand.java:252)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.SubmitXCommand.execute(SubmitXCommand.java:72)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:280)
    at org.apache.oozie.DagEngine.submitJob(DagEngine.java:108)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.V1JobsServlet.submitWorkflowJob(V1JobsServlet.java:188)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.V1JobsServlet.submitJob(V1JobsServlet.java:88)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseJobsServlet.doPost(BaseJobsServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.JsonRestServlet.service(JsonRestServlet.java:286)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter$2.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:384)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.oozie.command.CommandException: E0603: SQL error in operation, <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@355319a8
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.SubmitXCommand.execute(SubmitXCommand.java:231)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.oozie.executor.jpa.JPAExecutorException: E0603: SQL error in operation, <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@355319a8
    at org.apache.oozie.service.JPAService.execute(JPAService.java:228)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.SubmitXCommand.execute(SubmitXCommand.java:228)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@355319a8
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:594)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.JPAService.execute(JPAService.java:223)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@355319a8
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.newFlushException(BrokerImpl.java:2347)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2184)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2082)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:2000)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.LocalManagedRuntime.commit(LocalManagedRuntime.java:81)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.commit(BrokerImpl.java:1524)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.commit(DelegatingBroker.java:933)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:570)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: An SQL data change is not permitted for a read-only connection, user or database. {prepstmnt 2096695648 INSERT INTO WF_JOBS (id, app_name, app_path, conf, group_name, parent_id, run, user_name, bean_type, created_time, end_time, external_id, last_modified_time, log_token, proto_action_conf, sla_xml, start_time, status, wf_instance) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)} [code=20000, state=25502]
FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@355319a8
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4962)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4922)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:136)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:78)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:144)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushInternal(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:100)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flush(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.ConstraintUpdateManager.flush(ConstraintUpdateManager.java:550)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.ConstraintUpdateManager.flush(ConstraintUpdateManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.flush(BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:105)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:78)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.flush(JDBCStoreManager.java:732)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.flush(DelegatingStoreManager.java:131)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: An SQL data change is not permitted for a read-only connection, user or database. {prepstmnt 2096695648 INSERT INTO WF_JOBS (id, app_name, app_path, conf, group_name, parent_id, run, user_name, bean_type, created_time, end_time, external_id, last_modified_time, log_token, proto_action_conf, sla_xml, start_time, status, wf_instance) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)} [code=20000, state=25502]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:219)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:195)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$1000(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:59)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:1134)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:275)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JDBCStoreManager.java:1792)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:268)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:119)
    ... 48 more
2014-06-11 11:01:45,717  WARN V1JobsServlet:542 - USER[jakub] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000000-140611110030961-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[-] URL[POST http://puppetmaster:11000/oozie/v2/jobs?action=start] error[E0803], E0803: IO error, E0603: SQL error in operation, <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@355319a8
org.apache.oozie.servlet.XServletException: E0803: IO error, E0603: SQL error in operation, <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@355319a8
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.V1JobsServlet.submitWorkflowJob(V1JobsServlet.java:193)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.V1JobsServlet.submitJob(V1JobsServlet.java:88)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseJobsServlet.doPost(BaseJobsServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.JsonRestServlet.service(JsonRestServlet.java:286)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter$2.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:384)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.oozie.DagEngineException: E0803: IO error, E0603: SQL error in operation, <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@355319a8
    at org.apache.oozie.DagEngine.submitJob(DagEngine.java:115)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.V1JobsServlet.submitWorkflowJob(V1JobsServlet.java:188)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.oozie.command.CommandException: E0803: IO error, E0603: SQL error in operation, <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@355319a8
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.SubmitXCommand.execute(SubmitXCommand.java:252)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.SubmitXCommand.execute(SubmitXCommand.java:72)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:280)
    at org.apache.oozie.DagEngine.submitJob(DagEngine.java:108)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.oozie.command.CommandException: E0603: SQL error in operation, <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@355319a8
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.SubmitXCommand.execute(SubmitXCommand.java:231)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.oozie.executor.jpa.JPAExecutorException: E0603: SQL error in operation, <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@355319a8
    at org.apache.oozie.service.JPAService.execute(JPAService.java:228)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.SubmitXCommand.execute(SubmitXCommand.java:228)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@355319a8
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:594)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.JPAService.execute(JPAService.java:223)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@355319a8
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.newFlushException(BrokerImpl.java:2347)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2184)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2082)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:2000)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.LocalManagedRuntime.commit(LocalManagedRuntime.java:81)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.commit(BrokerImpl.java:1524)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.commit(DelegatingBroker.java:933)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:570)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: An SQL data change is not permitted for a read-only connection, user or database. {prepstmnt 2096695648 INSERT INTO WF_JOBS (id, app_name, app_path, conf, group_name, parent_id, run, user_name, bean_type, created_time, end_time, external_id, last_modified_time, log_token, proto_action_conf, sla_xml, start_time, status, wf_instance) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)} [code=20000, state=25502]
FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowJobBean@355319a8
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4962)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4922)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:136)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:78)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:144)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushInternal(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:100)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flush(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.ConstraintUpdateManager.flush(ConstraintUpdateManager.java:550)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.ConstraintUpdateManager.flush(ConstraintUpdateManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.flush(BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:105)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:78)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.flush(JDBCStoreManager.java:732)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.flush(DelegatingStoreManager.java:131)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: An SQL data change is not permitted for a read-only connection, user or database. {prepstmnt 2096695648 INSERT INTO WF_JOBS (id, app_name, app_path, conf, group_name, parent_id, run, user_name, bean_type, created_time, end_time, external_id, last_modified_time, log_token, proto_action_conf, sla_xml, start_time, status, wf_instance) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)} [code=20000, state=25502]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:219)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:195)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$1000(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:59)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:1134)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:275)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JDBCStoreManager.java:1792)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:268)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:119)
    ... 48 more
```

Neither oozie web console nor the resource manager noticed any job submission.
My suspition is that something with the installation is not correct.

Any hints where to look or what might cause the issue?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong user used during the installation process. This solved the problem:

```
sudo -u oozie /usr/lib/oozie/bin/ooziedb.sh create -sqlfile /usr/lib/oozie/oozie.sql -run
```

Instead of:

```
sudo /usr/lib/oozie/bin/ooziedb.sh create -sqlfile /usr/lib/oozie/oozie.sql -run
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps.

http://grokbase.com/p/cloudera/hue-user/1379cs2rg3/running-wordcount-job-designer-streaming

[An SQL data change is
not permitted for a read-only connection, user or database]

Answer (score 0):

already try @jaksky solution but still got the same error. it seems that user OOZIE don't have permission to access databases on mysql. so i try to grant all permission using GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'OOZIE'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ''; and it works now.

Comment: This should be a comment in the Answer, instead of its own answer. That way, you can follow up on it as a conversation